# How to compare two different column and highlight highest value in each row?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am aware of using MAX for conditional formatting however I am confused about how to compare two different columns. I would like to use conditional formatting to compare data/value from columns B and Columns E, then highlight the highest value in each row based on these two columns. I wonder if this is possible?

It does not seem working for this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXSOA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting to achieve this:

Select the entire range (for example, B1:E10)
Add a new conditional formatting rule.

Home >> Conditional Formatting >> New Rule >> Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

[image]

[image]

```
=($E1>$B1)
=($B1>$E1)
```

Just make sure you type the Formula rather than selecting the cell, or you will have the `$` symbol in the reference, which you don't want in the row reference.

Comment: Thank you, I assume this won't highlight any data in columns C and D?

Comment: Correct, as you can see in the bottom image, the format only applies to `=$B$1:$B$6` and `=$E$1:$E$6`.  You can change that to apply to any range you like, including C and D if required.

Answer (score 0):

So highlight the largest value in each row? That is possible using conditional formatting.

For example, if your entire data frame is in A2:B11, first do `=B2>A2` then `=A2>B2`.

The steps for conditional formatting are below:

1. highlight the full column of cells you wish to format (in this case, say A2:A11)
2. Home->Conditional Formatting->New Rule->"Use formula..."
3. Enter the above formula (being sure to unfreeze column and row references)
4. Format->Fill->Select Color->Okay->Okay

[image]

Comment: I am trying to compare far columns for example column B and Column E. Is that still possible using that as I try it...it won't work.

Comment: Sure thing, just replace Column A in the example with Column B for your data, and replace Column B in the example with Column E in your data (i.e. ```=B2>E2``` and then ```=E2>B2```). In both cases, make sure you are highlighting the full column you want to apply the formatting to first, and that you eliminate any frozen references (the dollar signs).

Comment: No problem, if you found it answered your question fully, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark